# Splitting a string in Racket

Tags: string, split, racket, idioms

I want to convert a string into a list of one strings in Racket:

```
(string-split-wishful "abcd" "") => (list "a" "b" "c" "d")
```

This is the function that I wish for. The closest thing is [`string-split`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fstring..rkt%29._string-split%29%29) which doesn't do what I want:

```
(string-split "abcd" "") => (list "" "a" "b" "c" "d" "")
```

How do I get rid of the superfluous empty strings at the beginning and the end? I know that I can do something like `(reverse (cdr (reverse (cdr (string-split "abcd" "")))))` but I want to know if there's a more idiomatic way of doing this.

Comment: You could use `(map string (string->list str))`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
(string-split "abcd" #rx"(?<=.)(?=.)")
; ==> ("a" "b" "c" "d")
```

It uses a regular expression instead of string and the regular expression consist of a zero-width positive look-behind assertion such that it only matches after a character and one zero-width positive look-ahead assertion such that the match need one char in its right side to match.

Alexis' suggestion is nice too, might even perform better too:

```
(map string (string->list "abcd"))
```

Comment: howto split expression into sub expressions?

Comment: Why does the default behavior with an empty-string separator produce the empty strings in the output?